# Update operation with thymleaf and spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, crud

I'm trying to develop a set new password function in my app.  When user open the set new password page, it has 3 input field: New password, new password again, and a hidden field, uuId. With this uuid can help me update the database properly record. I've made the two controller method, but something is wrong, because the uuid field did not filled.

```
<form id="newPassword" name="newPassword" th:action="@{/admin/createPassword}" th:object="${password}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-6">  <input autofocus class="form-control" id="uuid" name="uuid" th:value="*{uuid}"type="hidden"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="password1">Új jelszó</label><div class="col-md-6">
<input autofocus class="form-control" id="password1" name="password1" th:field="*{password1}" required type="password"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row"><label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="password2">Új jelszó mégegyszer</label>
<div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" required type="password" th:field="*{password2}"></div>
</div>
                            
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Elküld</button>
</div>
</form>


@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/setpassword/{uuId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String emailConfirm(Model model, @PathVariable("uuId") String uuId){
    System.out.println(uuId);
    model.addAttribute("password", new NewPasswordDto(uuId));
        return "/admin/newpassword";//file név

}
@PostMapping(value = "/admin/createPassword")
public ModelAndView newPassword(NewPasswordDto newPasswordDto) {
    userService.setAccountActive(newPasswordDto);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("/email/emailconfirmed");
    return mv;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have uuid property in NewPasswordDto object

Btw this missed space may cause the error too

[image]